# How can I update a specific array in postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sql-update

hello everyone I would like to know if there is an easy way to update an array. Im trying to update the first row of my column with a new array.

[image: Here is what im trying to do]

[image: Here is my table where im trying to update the first row of my column]

my postgreSQL version: PostgreSQL 12.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
update invitation_table
set invitee = '{1, 3, 4}'
where invitee = '{2, 5}'
```

Comment: hello im getting an error message could you help me out. the error is as follows: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 2: set invitee = {1, 3, 4}

Comment: @John: sorry, that was missing single quotes. Fixed.